# ColorThief.getColor() TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

Tags: node.js, color-thief

I'm trying to use ColorThief in the node.js environment. When invoking ColorThief.getColor() I get the follwing error:

> TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

The error results from this line of code in the module.

```
if(url.indexOf('data:image/gif;')
```

Here my code:

```
const ColorThief = require('colorthief');
const img = document.querySelector('#image');
ColorThief.getColor(img)
    .then(color => { console.log(color) })
    .catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

Any help solving this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief documentation

> getColor(image [, quality])
>
> image - When called in the browser, this argument expects an HTML image element, not a URL. When run in Node, this argument expects a path to the image.

Comment: Dear Bhathiya, thanks for the quick reply. So the solution was to call:`ColorThief.getColor(img.src)`.